# ¿Se entiende la expresión "pregunta de quesito" en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: modismos, hispanoamérica

En el [Trivial Pursuit](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Pursuit), el objetivo del juego es obtener todos los "quesitos" de colores.

[image: las piezas del juego]

> Si la casilla es una de las casillas especiales situadas en la intersección, obtiene como premio una de las seis **cuñas** (popularmente llamadas "**quesitos**") del color de la casillas
>
> <sub>Fuente: wikipedia</sub>

Al menos en España la expresión coloquial "pregunta de quesito" tiene las connotaciones de "pregunta especial", "rara" o "difícil", precisamente por estas preguntas del juego. Había preguntas normales y preguntas "de quesito". Las dos salían de las mismas tarjetas, pero cuando caías en la casilla la pregunta se volvía más importante, porque te hacía ganar uno de los codiciados quesitos.

Siempre entendí que la analogía era con los quesitos en porciones, [como los de El Caserío](http://es-pic2.ciao.com/es/17467317.jpg), porque era más difícil llamar a esas piezas "cuñas", "prismas" o "trocitos de tarta" (que también se le parecen).

Aun así no sé si esa denominación de "quesito" es "universal" o propia del español de España, y por ende no sé si el modismo se entiende en Hispanoamérica.

[image: mini Brie small]

¿Se entiende la expresión "pregunta de quesito" en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: No, y además suena muy graciosa. :)

Comment: @pablodf76, pues cuando saques un poco de tiempo pon una respuesta tipo "yo soy de Argentina (porque no todo el mundo sabe quiénes somos y [de dónde somos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2587/5481)) y por lo menos aquí no se entiende esa expresión". Con ese _contraejemplo_ es suficiente, y la acepto como respuesta.

Comment: Tal vez es lo que aquí llamamos **[la pregunta del millón](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/la+pregunta+del+mill%C3%B3n.html)**

Comment: Me gusta, pero yo no lo hubiera entendido.  Para mí (oído mexicano), *quesito* es queso especial, queso pequeño, queso con cariño, queso porque de veras quiero que comas algo aunque sea pequeño antes de irte a la escuela.

Comment: @aparente001 Eso me causó bastante gracia, en especial lo final. Recuerdo cuando mi mamá me imploraba que comiera algo antes de salir a la escuela por las mañanas, algo a la par de *Ándale, no te vayas con la tripa de faról, comete un taquito. Mira, aquí hay quesito.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La expresión "pregunta de quesito" no se entiende, al menos, en Argentina y Colombia. Quizá tenga que ver con que el Trivial Pursuit no es/fue tan conocido aquí, para empezar, por lo cual el cómo denominar esta clase de pregunta ni siquiera se presentó como interrogante.

Comment: ¿Y la palabra *quesito* o solo se usa en España? El DLE si que la recoge: http://dle.rae.es/?id=UogN7sl

Comment: En Colombia tampoco entendemos "pregunta de quesito" además que aquí el [quesito es un producto derivado de la leche que poco se parece al verdadero queso](https://www.mycolombianrecipes.com/quesito-colombiano-colombian-fresh-cheese).

Comment: En Argentina un quesito es una porción o pedazo pequeño de queso, o un diminutivo apreciativo de *queso*.